# Average and Total in a Calculated Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, calculated-column

I am currently calculating the difference between created date and modified date in my SharePoint custom list.

Is it possible to also calculate the average of the # of days, totalled by month?

I am using Sharepoint 2013 on-premise with SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not natively provide rollup totals for calculated columns, but you do have some options on-prem.

You can get the total number of days between the two dates for each row with the following calculated column formula:

```
=DATEDIF(Modified,Created,"d")
```

To emulate a rollup value, you will need to do some JavaScript trickery.  [This article](https://www.metrostarsystems.com/enterprise-it/sharepoint-calculated-column-total/) provides a how-to create a javascript-based calculated "Total" column.  You would of course need to modify the line of code the sets the `var TotalSum=` to calculate your average instead of a sum.